# Prove that permutation group is automorphism group of some structure

Tags: group-theory, permutations, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a permutation group on $X= \{ x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$

Prove that  $Aut(X,G)=G$

---

I have no ideas how to prove it.

Besides, there is a question that the problem asks to prove $Aut(X,G) = G $ , i.e. prove automorphism group with the structure (permutation group G) is the permutation group.

But, in context the textbook says that we indeed prove **every permutation group  is the automorphism group of some object** .

What's the connected?

---

Here are some definitions from textbook

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $\operatorname{Aut}(X,G)$ is a subset of $S(X)$, the group of all permutations of $X$. By definition a permutation $\sigma\in S(X)$ is an automorphism of $(X,G)$ if and only if $G\sigma=G$. In particular this implies that $e\sigma=\sigma\in G$, which shows that $\operatorname{Aut}(X,G)\subset G$. On the other hand, for all $g\in G$ you have $Gg=G$ and hence $g\in\operatorname{Aut}(X,G)$, which shows that $G\subset\operatorname{Aut}(X,G)$. Hence $\operatorname{Aut}(X,G)=G$.

This shows that $G$ is the automorphism group of $(X,G)$. As $G$ was an arbitrary permutation group to begin with, this proves that every permutation group is an automorphism group.

Comment: Thanks! I have realized almost things but the $e\sigma=\sigma\in G$. The $\sigma$ is permutation like $(g_1) \sigma = g_2$. How can I derive it?

Comment: Well $g_1,g_2\in G$ and $G$ is a group, so $g_1^{-1}g_2\in G$.

Comment: Or $\sigma$ is not a permutation function ($S(X)$)? how to say a function is a element in $G$

Comment: By definition $G$ is a subset of $S(X)$.